# How to configure and use all the IPs given by my provider?

Tags: routing, ip, configuration, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-20.04

Need assistance on how to use all the Ips given from my hosting provider. Currently i have 5 IPs that is routable and can be used on any circumstances. I wanted to make a new environment on my dedicated server such as VPS inside. Eventough ive able to make the VM(Virtual Machine) but then i still cannot or not understand on how to assign them the specific ip. I used ubuntu 20.04 and KVM as my hypervisor. is there any help? should i configure more on netplan or inside virsh net-edit. or is there any other else that i should do ?

Here is my netplan

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0f0:
      addresses:
      - 146.111.211.10/29
      gateway4: 146.111.211.9
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      addresses:
      - 146.111.211.11/29
      gateway4: 146.111.211.9
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      addresses:
      - 146.111.201.12/29
      gateway4: 146.11.211.9
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      addresses:
      - 146.111.201.13/29
      gateway4: 146.111.211.9
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
    enp3s0f1:
      dhcp4: true
    enp4s0f0:
      dhcp4: true
    enp4s0f1:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

P/S: the ip is dummy ip.

Comment: How exactly did you set up the virtual network? This netplan suggests that you have not done so.

Comment: thats my default netplan. it just shows that i have many ips. i currently lost and dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Typically via a firewall and using VirtualIP's where you can then use 1 ip for your firewall and the rest for internal systems you want to have a service exposed to the internet.. example: a web server.